# How can I solve $(y+2)^2 y' + (x + 2y + 3)^2 = 0 $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck trying to solve this ODE and I wonder if someone can help, thanks in advance. The ODE is the following:

$$(y+2)^2 y' + (x + 2y + 3)^2 = 0 $$

I first tried expanding the squared terms and trying to separate the variables but it was not very helpful. Then I noticed that the equation is homogenious but trying to make a substitution got me nowhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As given, it is not homogeneous, but you can make a substitution to make it homogeneous: $Y = y+2$, $X = x - 1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Substitute $y=Y+k$, $x=X+h$ to do away with the constant terms. Then this will reduce to homogeneous form when the substitution $Y=VX\Rightarrow Y'=V+XV'$ works.

On first substituion, you will find $k=-2, h=1$.